# angular auido not working when page loaded

Tags: angular, audio

I want to add music to my website and it to start with the music. the music starts only when the picture is clicked. As you can see i want to start when page loaded but it cant be. I have to click publick changed function double times for start music? Why?

```
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit{

sounddata:string = "/assets/images/sound-close.png";

auth:boolean = false;

audio = new Audio()


ngOnInit(){
  this.audio.src = "/assets/images/snowambient.mp3";
  this.audio.load();
  this.audio.loop = true;

  this.changed();
}


public changed(){

  this.auth = !this.auth;

  console.log("im here")

  if(this.auth == true){

  
    console.log("im here2")
    this.sounddata = "/assets/images/sound-close.png";
    return this.audio.play();
  }
  else if(this.auth == false){
  

    this.sounddata = "/assets/images/sound-open.png";
    return this.audio.pause();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently browsers are strcting autoplay policies in order to improve the user experience. For example, if you are using Google Chrome, autoplay policies are:

- Muted autoplay is always allowed.
- Autoplay with sound is allowed if:

  - The user has interacted with the domain (click, tap, etc.).
  - On desktop, the user's Media Engagement Index threshold has been crossed,
    meaning the user has previously played video with sound.
  - The user has added the site to their home screen on mobile or installed the PWA on desktop.
- Top frames can delegate autoplay permission to their iframes to allow autoplay with sound.